# TSQL: How to Copy value from one column from the previous row into the next row in a different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table where I want to update the value of Location/Description from the value of  Number.

For eg: The 2nd row in the table should have a Loaction/Descritption as "Freezer Twnety".  Like wise the last 2 rows should have Location/Description as  "Freezer Thirty"".

The NUMBER column is an ID and somehow that column got populated by Location/Description values. I want to update back them to the right place and delete all the rows that just contain the "Freezer%" as NUMBER.

```
╔══════════╦════════════════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ Location ║     Number     ║ Tissue ║ Description ║
╠══════════╬════════════════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║ NULL     ║ FREEZER TWENTY ║ NULL   ║ NULL        ║
║ NULL     ║ BRC13091917    ║ 13828  ║ NULL        ║
║ NULL     ║ Freezer Three  ║ NULL   ║ NULL        ║
║ NULL     ║ BRC13091922    ║ 13867  ║ NULL        ║
║ NULL     ║ FREEZER THIRTY ║ NULL   ║ NULL        ║
║ NULL     ║ BRC13112118    ║ 14815  ║ NULL        ║
║ NULL     ║ BRC13112118    ║ 14816  ║ NULL        ║
╚══════════╩════════════════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Also rows don't have any inherent order and it doesn't look as though you have any suitable column for ordering?

Comment: Not possible.  A select statement with no order by may have returned the rows in that order but that does not mean the rows have an order.

Comment: Hi Martin, I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: It was given to me in a spreadhseet. The thing is the "Freezer%" is the value for Location/Description for n no. of next rows till we get to another "Freezer%".  So sometimes it is just one row and sometimes 2, 3 etc like this.

Comment: If you have this in a spreadsheet, you are better off using a scripting language to fix this than trying with SQL.

Comment: Hi Simbabque. Can you please elaborate ?  Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably have an XLS spreadsheet. Save it as CSV and use a scripting language to read the file and fix it. The algorithm is simple. Read line by line; split into an array; look at the column with the `FREEZER`, if there is a freezer, save it and read next line; if not, put the saved location into the missing field;write out the file; - I just wrote it in Perl. I can post it as an answer, but you will probably not know what to do with it.

Comment: See my updated answer for a tool that might do all the work.

Comment: -1 You have got to be kidding me.  You have data in Excel and you tag it SQL.

Comment: Blam, the data was in excel but I moved it into a SQL Table. I have to insert this data anyways in another SQL Table. So I believe the Tag was justified.

Comment: Excel has a row number.  BIG difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with something a lot better. I built it in JavaScript and [put it in a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cCRq3/). Just save your spreadsheet as a CSV file with `;` as delimiter, copy everything in the top `<div>` and run it. You can copy the output back into a text file, save as CSV and open in Excel.

---

It is a lot easier to solve this with a programming language than to do it in SQL. If you have a spreadsheet, you can turn it into CSV to make it easier to read. You can then fill in the blanks and remove the wrong lines. Here's a solution in Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strictures;
use Data::Dump;
use 5.012;

my $location;
while (my $row = <DATA>) {
  chomp $row;
  my @fields = split /;/, $row;
  if ($fields[1] =~ m/^FREEZER/i) {
    $location = $fields[1];
    next;
  }
  say join ';', $location, map { $_ // '' } @fields[1, 2, 3];
}

__DATA__
;FREEZER TWENTY;;
;BRC13091917;13828;
;Freezer Three;;
;BRC13091922;13867;
;FREEZER THIRTY;;
;BRC13112118;14815;
;BRC13112118;14816;
```

The output looks like this:

```
FREEZER TWENTY;BRC13091917;13828;
Freezer Three;BRC13091922;13867;
FREEZER THIRTY;BRC13112118;14815;
FREEZER THIRTY;BRC13112118;14816;
```

---

Since you are most likely on Windows you did not come to this conclusion yourself you will probably not know what to do with this. The algorithm is the same in any programming language, though. You could do it in VBA in Excel, or in PHP, or anything else.

- read the file line by line
- split the line into an array
- check if there is a location in the 2nd column

  - if yes:

    - save that in a variable that stays intact when moving to the next line
    - proceed to next line
  - if no:

    - replace the empty 1st column with the saved location
  - write out the line to a new file

Comment: Thank you :-).. I got it.. I just tried and it worked. I have 4-5 files like these. Will do for all of them on monday.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it in t-sql
(Replace *YourTable* with your table name):

```
With [Rows] 
As
(
    Select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select 0)) As RowNum
    From YourTable
),
[Titles] 
As
(
    Select *
    From [Rows] r
    Where Tissue Is Null
)
Update x
Set Location = t.Number, [Description] = t.Number
From YourTable x, [Rows] r,  [Titles] t
Where x.Tissue Is Not Null
And r.Number = x.Number 
And r.Tissue = x.Tissue
And t.RowNum = ( Select MAX(RowNum) From [Titles] t2 Where r.RowNum > t2.RowNum )
```